# How To Auto Delete CAPTCHA Images CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I am using the CAPTCHA helper in CodeIgniter, documentation found here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html. When I set the `'expiration'` parameter it never seems to make a difference, the CAPTCHA images are never deleted by the system. I am running CodeIgniter on my local Windows 7 PC using XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else found in this situation, it does work, although it does need `create_captcha()` to be run again to remove all the previous images. This means there will always be at least one captcha image left on the system.